# How to create "a kind of" Google Maps based on a large image

Tags: google-maps

A have a large image (png 10000x10000 px), and based on that image I need to create a kind of Google Maps, with zoom, drags, markers, etc.

I did a search but can not find the starting point, tools and technologies used.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Question is too broad, what research, did you do? What code have you tried? What error messages did you get? If you can't answer those questions, you need to do more research. StackOverflow is not for suggestions, it's for code you have written but is buggy.

Comment: Maybe you could add the image (or perhaps a smaller version!) to your question so we have some idea what you're expecting to be able to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a more simple solution than what jatinderjit suggests:

1. Chop your "large" image into **tiles**, so that users do not need to download the entire image if they are zoomed out a lot, or if they are viewing just a small part of it. You could use TileMill, gdal2tiles, zoomify, etc. Note that if your image does not have to match the real world, you do not need to georeference it, nor to use GeoTIFF format.
2. Have your tiles hosted on a server. Any server is fine, as your tiles are only standard images (but you may have *thousands* of them). If your application is purely local (executed on a few machines, possibly with no Internet connection), you can even simply copy-paste your tiles on each machine drive.
3. Use a low-level mapping library to use your own tiles (e.g. Leaflet, OpenLayers 3, etc.), or an online service that offers usage of uploaded content (whether a large image that the service can chop for you, or directly your tiles).

Note: regarding JuanMendes' comment on your question, he may be referring to 
[Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), which is indeed the appropriate place when you come with just requirements for software solution.

Comment: Thank you thank you very much. I can now create a prototype with the tools you provided me.

Answer (score 1):

To create a "kind of" map from an image, first you need to georeference that image, which you can do with the help of [QGIS](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html).
Export this in GeoTiff format (a raster format) from there. Now you've got a map.

Next you'll need a server to serve the map (example:  [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com), where can upload this GeoTiff file. It'll create tiles from your image).

After you've got a map and a server, all that is left is for you to write actual code to interact with the map (you can use [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com) or Mapbox's own fork of leaflet - [mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/)).